Transparent background and rounded corners css
Please tell me how to solve this problem: the block has a nested block in the upper left corner. I need the space between the nested block and the main block to be transparent, and all the corners of the main block to be rounded. only css solutions. Maybe someone has encountered this problem and is there a solution? Thank you!


https://css-shape.com/inverted-radius/ (https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-create-shapes-with-inner-curves-using-css-mask)
